Question in an example of prime decomposition in an extension of DVRs.
Choose any element $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}[[x]]$ such that it is transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}(x)$(This is possible by comparing cardinalities.), and let $\beta=\alpha^2$.
Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(x,\beta)$, $L=\mathbb{Q}(x,\alpha)$, $A=K\cap \mathbb{Q}[[x]]$, $B=L\cap \mathbb{Q}[[x]]$. Then, $L/K$ is a finitely separable algebraic extension of degree 2, and both $A$ and $B$ are DVRs with residue field $\mathbb{Q}$, and $B$ is the integral closure of $A$ in $L$. Thus we can use the theorem of prime decomposition in this stage.
Consider the prime ideal $xA\subset A$. $xB\subset B$ is also prime, hence the ramification index $e=1$. $B/xB=\mathbb{Q}=A/xA$, hence the residue class degree $f=1$. We get $ef=1\neq2$!
Could you tell me which step is false?
